# Ubuntu 18.04 CUPS permissions

Tags: 18.04, permissions, printing, canon

I'm trying to use my **Canon LBP6000** printer on Ubuntu 18.04 with CUPS.
I guess I'm done with printer install but, I can't print anything.

```
"loadFilename failed: open /var/spool/cups/d00025-001: Permission denied"
```

This message, is what I see in a CUPS web page.
Obviously it's a permission issue. but I still can't resolve it.

I've add my only user to `lp` and `lpadmin` groups. I've even try `sudo chmod 777 /var/spool/cups/`

Any ideas would be appreciated

Comment: That directory is owned by the ```lp``` group by default.So I don't know why that doesn't work. Have you tried **chown**ing the directory ```/var/spool/cups/``` ?Try ```sudo chown username /var/spool/cups/``` to change that temporarily.

Answer (score 1):

For those who have this problem and tried any solution they found: I found that setfacl can make problems with permissions on /var/spool/cups folder, so try to disable it:

```
setfacl -bn /var/spool/cups
```

or try to set ownership to /var/spool/cups folder

```
sudo chown -R lp:lp /var/spool/cups
```

or

```
sudo chown -R root:lp /var/spool/cups
```

Comment: tnx I'll give it a shot

Comment: +1 removing acl with `setfacl -Rbn /var/spool/cups` and on cups-pdf solved the problem for me